# script to replace first line of file if it DOESN"T match a certain pattern

Tags: python, ruby, perl, sed

I would like to add some license text to all files that do not have
a license. So, I want to check the first line of the file, and if it doesn't
have the text "#region License" in it, to insert some text. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to keep or remove the `#region License` line?

Comment: I want to add "#region License\n#endregion" if "#region License" is not present

Answer (score 3):

The following one-liner will insert the text `#region License` on the first line of files that don't already start with that text:

```
perl -i.bckp -ne 'print && next if $. > 1;/^#region License/?print:print"#region License\n$_"' filename.txt
```

It also makes backup files with the `.bckp` extension of your files.

Comment: thanks!  I am on windows - this script seems to change the line endings.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -i -e '1{/#region License/!i\some text' -e '}' file1 file2 file....
```

Comment: cool. Can "some text" be multi line? I want to add  "#region License\n#endregion

Comment: It works for me. I'm using GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...well the one-liners are a bit too clever for me.  Conventionally you might try something like this:

```
foreach(glob('my/files-*.dat')) 
{
   open IFH,'<',$);
   my $rec = <IFH>;
   if($rec =~ m/#region License/)
    {
        close IFH;
        next;
   }

    open OFH,'>',"$_.tmp";
    print OFH "#region License .....\n";
    print OFH $rec;
    print OFH <IFH>;
    close IFH;
    close OFH;  
    unlink $_;
    rename $_.tmp $_;
}
```

Comment: Not checking the return value from `open`? Bad example code! No cookie! :-)